# Allow airflow access to docker sock using docker v2 on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, file-permissions

I am having many issues testing Airflow in a container using Docker. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1327, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Here are the details of my setup:

Host machine

```
> lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I tested it with [Docker Desktop for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/) version `2.15` and `2.16`, these versions include Docker Engine and Compose together, so I only had to install that.

I have checked many threads about how to fix this issue but none of those solutions actually solved my issue. I tried:

- Changing the permissions of the `/var/run/Docker.sock` file to `666` and even `777`
- Enabling the non-root option ([link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/))
- Adding my user to the docker user group

I was able to "solve" this issue by downgrading Docker compose version to V1 (without any extra steps, no need for any changes on permissions), but thats not a proper solution as I had to jump back to a deprecated version of Docker.

Any idea is welcomed. Thanks!